# How to find correct policies for aws_api_gateway_integration Terraform resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-policies

I want to create infra and find the minimum permissions required for the user to perform terraform deployment and follow best practices. The issue is with AWS API Gateway, which makes me puzzled about the permissions I need to give users.

The idea is that API Gateway has methods and mapping before pushing it further to SQS.

The snippet of Terraform I am running is below:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "apiSQS" {
  name = "${var.integration}-${var.stage}-apigateway_sqs"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "integration-api-gateway"{
  name = "${var.integration}-${var.stage}-api"
  description = "Parse and send messages to SQS"
  endpoint_configuration {
    types = ["REGIONAL"]
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "booking" {
    rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.integration-api-gateway.id
    parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.integration-api-gateway.root_resource_id
    path_part   = "booking"
}


# booking/create
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "create" {
    rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.integration-api-gateway.id
    parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.booking.id
    path_part   = "create"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "method_create" {
    rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.integration-api-gateway.id
    resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.create.id
    http_method   = "POST"
    authorization = "NONE"

    request_parameters = {
      "method.request.path.proxy" = false
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "create_integration" {
  rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.integration-api-gateway.id
  resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.create.id
  http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.method_create.http_method
  type                    = "AWS"
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  credentials             = aws_iam_role.apiSQS.arn
  uri                     = "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.region}:sqs:path/${aws_sqs_queue.bookings-sqs.name}"

  request_parameters = {
    "integration.request.header.Content-Type" = "'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'"
  }

  # Request Template for passing Method, Body, QueryParameters and PathParams to SQS messages
  request_templates = {
    "application/json" = <<EOF
Action=SendMessage&MessageBody={
  "data": $util.urlEncode($input.body),
  "token": "$input.params('token')"
}
EOF
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.api_exec_role
  ]
}

# Mapping SQS Response
resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "method_create_response_200" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.integration-api-gateway.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.create.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.method_create.http_method
  status_code = 200
  response_models = {
    "application/json" = "Empty"
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "create_integration_response" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.integration-api-gateway.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.create.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.method_create.http_method
  status_code = aws_api_gateway_method_response.method_create_response_200.status_code
  response_templates = {
    "application/json" = "Empty"
  }
  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_integration.create_integration
  ]
}
```

**Error is:**

```
╷
│ Error: Error creating API Gateway Integration: AccessDeniedException: 
│       status code: 403, request id: 4f6a7ab0-3551-4ea0-80a4-4f89edbaad8c
│ 
│   with aws_api_gateway_integration.create_integration,
│   on main.tf line 212, in resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "create_integration":
│  212: resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "create_integration" {
│ 
╵
```

The latest policy I attached to the user is:

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "apigateway:*"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/*"
  ]
}
```

Am I missing anything here? How can I find missing policies?

I searched StackOverflow, GitHub, and Googled the issue but so far, no luck. I tried to run the same code with Administration rights, and it worked fine. Any idea?

**UPDATE 1:**

I have tried IAM Access Analyzer, and it didn't help much. It generated some nonsense.

**UPDATE 2:**

Based on the previous step, I enabled `AWS CloudTrail` and found events I need to reproduce:

- GetIntegration
- PutIntegration
- DeleteIntegration

I found a [reference doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/api/API_PutIntegration.html)

Any idea how to progress further?

Comment: That policy matches the managed `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonAPIGatewayAdministrator` policy, which should give you all the permission you need. I would check CloudTrail to see what API call is being rejected.

Comment: I think the URI has to be different, something like `arn:aws:apigateway:${var.region}:sqs:action/SendMessage`.

Comment: @MarkoE where the URI should be different? I still didn't get it working unless I gave full IAM permission to the account.